# How can I encourage my cat to eat after treated megacolon?

Tags: cats, health, eating

My cat had megacolon for 3-4 days. He was apathetic, did not eat, and when he eventually ate, he vomited.

[image: Cat X-Ray]

Two days ago the vet used enema that helped to empty the colon through fecal vomiting. The blood tests is ideal so for 99% it seems the problem was not caused by any illness.

Now the cat is more happy and playful but still not very eager to eat. I gave him a bowl of Royal Canin Fibre Response, recommended by the vet for problems with constipation. Initially the cat smelled it, tried and spat it out. I added a bit of tuna sauce from a can to encourage him and he ate a few bits of food yesterday and a few today but still very little.

How can I encourage my cat to eat food?

The cat has not pooped either since the enema, two days ago. Perhaps because he has no material to poop... or there is still some problem. Before megacolon he used to have two meals a day (48g in total) of dry food.

Comment: Have you considered that the constipation may be caused by dry food? Does your cat have plenty of fresh water to drink?

Comment: @Mick Right, it might be caused by that and other things: I hadn't been grooming him recently, I played less with him, so he has less move. And yes, I served him mainly dry food. The wet suggested to use recommended Royal Canine dry food for a few weeks, but it looks he was wrong.

Comment: We have only kept a cat for a few years, and he has not experienced any problems with constipation, so I can't give you much advice re cats. However, we used to keep dogs, and these did sometimes get constipated. Their diet was mostly wet (tinned) food mixed with dog biscuit. The solution was simple enough. We soaked the biscuit in boiling water, and gave it to the dogs after it had cooled down.

Comment: Royal canin fibre dry is better than wet for constipation, although I 100% would rather feed wet to kitties in this case your vet was correct. Megacolon is lifelong and we typically also prescribe lactulose to be given daily if food does not help.

Comment: @RebeccaRVT The problem is that the cat does not want now to eat dry Royal Canin Fibre. I started to serve wet food with lactulose and psyllium seeds - the cat eats it and poops.